# On button click focus input

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2

I am trying to autofocus input on button click but it doesn't work. Code can be found here for edit.

I also have an error in the console if you can help me:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'inp' (at (index):19:210)

Thank you,

I appreciate any help

```
<div class="test">
 <span id="icon-s" onclick="myFunction()" class="toggle-tab">btn click <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br></span>
</div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search here..." class="input-text" maxlength="128" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="both" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="true">
    </div>
</div>




<script>
    // Select input and button
    const inp = document.querySelector('#search');
    const btn = document.querySelector('#icon-s');

    // Focus input on button click
    btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
        inp.disabled = false;
        inp.focus();
        inp.select();
    })

    // Disable input after clicking outside of input
    inp.addEventListener('blur' , () => {
        inp.disabled = true;
    })

    // Edit username after clicking enter
    inp.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) inp.disabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing in the console is because you are missing the 'event' parameter in your 'keyup' event listener. Here's the corrected code with the missing 'event' parameter added:

```
<script>
// Select input and button
const inp = document.querySelector('#search');
const btn = document.querySelector('#icon-s');

// Focus input on button click
btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    inp.disabled = false;
    inp.focus();
    inp.select();
})

// Disable input after clicking outside of input
inp.addEventListener('blur' , () => {
    inp.disabled = true;
})

// Edit username after clicking enter
inp.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) inp.disabled = true;
});
```

As for the autofocus issue, it seems that your code is working correctly. When you click the button, the input field is focused and selected. However, if you want to autofocus the input field when the page loads, you can add the 'autofocus' attribute to the input element like this:

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search here..." class="input-text" maxlength="128" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="both" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="true" autofocus>
```

This will autofocus the input field when the page loads.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I tried as you said but I get the same error in the console.

do you have a better idea how i could do this lurcu?

Thank you